# Electric arc and electric spark differences?

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, electric-current, voltage, ions

Why does an electric spark occur discontinuously while an electric arc is not extinguished as long as the current is maintained?

Comment: Your question amounts to asking why we call a continuous electrical discharge an "arc," when we call a momentary discharge a "spark?" I think this question would be better suited for https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How is this different from your (answered) question yesterday (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/595577/what-is-the-difference-between-electric-spark-and-electric-arc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in case of a spark the current is not maintained - it is a capacitor-like discharge (as opposed to an EMF in case of an arc).